# Why does the anisotropic diffusion tensor have off-diagonal values?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In the most general case, when we want to describe anisotropic diffusion, the diffusion coefficient is a symmetric positive definite 3 by 3 matrix (they call it diffusion tensor). What do the off-diagonal values represent? Why is a diagonal matrix not enough? If we are interested in the diffusivity in a certain direction than we just add up the diagonal entries accordingly, just like we would do when calculating directional derivatives, no?

Comment: You are aware that the mass flux is equal to minus the dot product of the diffusion tensor and the concentration gradient, right?

Comment: Yes, so I think of it in such a manner: The concentration gradient tells us in which direction, how much things want to move, just based on the current concentration. But then there is another factor, which is the diffusivity of the medium, how much it lets the flow happen in a certain direction. This is the tensor. But why is it not diagonal?

Comment: Suppose you have a concentration gradient in the x-direction only.  The off-diagonal terms allow the max flux to have components in the y and z direction.  Otherwise, this would not be possible.

Comment: Oh, maybe now I understand. I assumed the diffusion coefficient can only affect the gradient, but if there is no gradient, than it cannot act upon anything. But from your answer I conclude that the medium itself can induce movement, is that right?

Comment: Imagine a foam cube with diagonally aligned wires in it. If I apply a temperature gradient from top to bottom, heat will also move left to right, down the thermally conductive wires. Now imagine a microstructure whose atomic arrangement produces the same effect.